# Notching and dimensioning a lot of 2x lumber to a specific size

Tags: table-saw, lumber

I need to cut 32 of these:

[image][image]

They're 2x8's, each a foot long, with a corner removed.  I'm hoping to cut them safely and efficiently.  I thought about running them across the table saw, maybe 3 or 4 at a time, for the short side of the notch then using a jig saw for the rest but that seems like a slow way to go and I'm not sure it's the safest.  Is there a better way to do this?

The first drawing is upside down for its actual use.  Here's how the pieces will be installed:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Obviously there are multiple ways of doing this, and since you have a table saw making use it for at least part of the operation makes sense. If I were making these I'd set up stop blocks on the fence, do all of the short and long cuts in batches, then simply finish off the cuts by hand. There's no need to break out the jigsaw for these, this is a 2-minute job for a handsaw, even doing them one at a time; however here it is completely safe to stack them together and saw multiples in one go.

Comment: Now all the above aside, can I ask the reason for the design decision for these to be this shape? I'm trying to figure out why a simple notch (e.g. as cut by a dado stack, with the wood clamped upright in a crosscut sled) wouldn't be the way to go here. Simpler, faster job and, bonus, these pieces would then hold that long 2x4 running through the centre of whatever this is more securely.

Comment: @Graphus The dado set would be the fastest way to do this but I don't have one that will cut 3-1/2" deep. I don't think I've ever seen one that large. The third pic might help explain. This is the edge of a deck with a "picture frame" border. The main decking boards (left) end just past the 2x4 so the ends are supported. Then a perpendicular board, supported by the outermost joist and the tops of the new blocking, covers the ends of the main deck boards. The picture frame is mitered at the corners of the deck so no ends are visible. The posts are bolted through the large blocking sections.

Comment: I have cut notches in wood framing similar to this without a dado using a standard blade to cut each side and then using a chisel to break the waste block free.

Comment: You can still do what I suggested without a dado stack, I was just giving one example of how it could be done. As @Ashlar says you can simply cut both sides of the notch with a standard blade and then use a chisel, or Norm Abram style, cut either side and then nibble away the material in the centre with multiple passes (again, with the wood held in a crosscut sled). Anyway, all this aside *why is a notch needed at all*? No additional sideways support seems to be required to me — you could just use pieces 3 3/4" x 12"... toenail the 2x4 in place onto those, it won't be going anywhere!

Comment: These comments are sufficiently appropriate answers! It's a good, well-presented Question. It should be graced with an Answer...

Comment: @Graphus You may be onto something. One more picture. It shows four configurations. The first is the original idea. Next is your suggestion of eliminating the notch. Only problem there is that there's no support for the long picture frame board. The third option moves the 2x4 under the gap between the boards to support them both. I want to avoid that because it provides a space for moisture and litter to collect and rot without falling through. The last idea may be a reasonable compromise with two 2x4s, one supporting the decking board ends and the other supporting the picture frame. Thoughts?

Comment: I'm a firm believer in the KISS principle, and so much framing *is* an example of keeping things simple. There's no compromise in strength that I see with not using any form of notched rests here, since there are no sideways forces anyway. But even if there were, toenailed in that long 2x4 would be very resistant to them. Anyway, FWIW I would definitely support the inside edge of that picture-frame piece rather than leave it float somewhat. [contd]

Comment: Something that didn't occur to me until just now, even though we've now given options for making this relatively simply you could build the L-shaped support rather than try to make it as a single-piece element, by simply glueing on the small blocks using construction adhesive or epoxy by preference (since neither need clamping pressure for a strong join). So you sort of go with your original plan, just approach it in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, but personally I would do stopped cuts on the table saw.  I would definitely *not* try to stack multiple pieces though.  (If you have access to a high-powered bandsaw that might be a better choice.)

For the longer rip cut I would use the fence and clamp a stop block to it to prevent overshooting your line.  For the crosscut I'd use a crosscut sled if available or else a miter gauge.  You should also be able to set up a stop block for this.

You'll probably need to finish each cut with a jigsaw (or band saw if available) since the circular tablesaw blade won't be able to fully get into the corner without overshooting on one side.

Also, you should be aware that the short leg of the L will be fairly weak due to the grain orientation.

Comment: Cutting them flat on the table is probably safer.  I had thought of cutting them upright as shown, at least for the short crosscut.  I don't have a bandsaw, but cutting most of the way with the table saw and finishing the cuts with a jig saw should work well.  I agree the short leg will be weak, but it shouldn't be a problem in it's intended use.

Comment: I hadn't thought of cutting them upright.  I suppose that would be safe enough if you make the crosscut first.  I'd want a tall fence on your miter gauge if you're going to do that.  You'll be maxing out the capacity of a 10" saw for that, but a 12" will be fine.